# Yii2 ajax render image after call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

So basically I have a controller that handles files (images & videos) and on the "view" view I have a button that's called "view content". That button is using the controller `actionContent($id)` and I want it when pressed to run the AJAX call to the action & render in-page in a `div` the  image that's located in the model with `id == $id`. How can I handle the AJAX request and return the image displayed in the `div`?

```
public function actionContent($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        switch (substr($model->mime, 0, strpos($model->mime, '/'))) {
            case 'image' :
                return $this->renderAjax('_image', [
                    'img' => $model->getFullPath(),
                ]);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

And the view:

```
 <span class="pull-right">
            <?= Html::a('View Content', ['content', 'id' => $model->id], [
                'class' => 'btn btn-default',
                'id' => 'content'
            ]); ?>
        </span>
```

With the script I already tried:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#content').click(function () {
            $(this).preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: $(this).href,
                contentType: "<?= $model->mime?>",
                success: function (response) {
                    ('.show-content').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + response + '" />');
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: You mean `event.preventDefault()`, not `$(this).preventDefault()`, add `event` as a parameter to the click handler (function). Your script looks generally okay, should perform a GET request to the server at least once.

Comment: what is returned from the view `_image`?, show the contents of the file

Comment: and what is the current problem you are having ?

Comment: sorry for the delay on my response, been busy with uni...
`
<?php
/* @var $img string */
?>

<img src="<?= $img ?>" alt="">
`
this is the page, i just want to render it without the reload of the page, thus using ajax seemed a good way to do so. Don't really know if this is the right way to do so.